# Showing that a complete and countable metric space has an open singleton set.

Tags: general-topology

My thoughts were of somehow constructing a Cauchy sequence and, by completeness, this point would likely be the singleton set in question. In terms of creating the sequence, I thought of taking countable intersections at some point to isolate that point from the rest of the metric space.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to answer this question. One can use the fact that a countable metric space *without* isolated points is homeomorphic to the rational numbers, and therefore cannot be complete; or that a countable complete metric space is homeomorphic to a countable ordinal with the order topology; or by other several ways.

Comment: Can you think of any ways that appeal more to someone in an introductory analysis class, in that the proof follows from the hypotheses.

Comment: Yes, it is often a good thing to point out what you know or don't know (read: in what sort of course this assignment was given).

Comment: The contrapositive: *A nonempty  complete metric space with no isolated points is uncountable*.  Note: I added "nonempty".  Don't you think the empty set is a counterexample to your statement?

Answer (score 3):

Let $X = \{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ and assume for a contradiction that each $\{x_n\} $ has empty interior. This immediately gives a contradiction to Baire's category theorem, because each of the sets  is closed and  thus nowhere dense by assumption.

EDIT: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem for the statement and a proof of the theorem, which you could try to adapt if you want to avoid using the theorem itself.

Comment: That makes sense, it didn't occur to me to use Baire-Category, thank you so much.

Comment: For the assumption, why are we assuming that each $\{ x_n\}$ has nonempty interior? Are we just assuming that not of the singleton sets are open? Why if not open implies having a nonempty interior? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Korn: For a singleton set, being open is the same as having non-empty interior (think about it!)

Comment: ummm.. I thought we were assuming that none of the singleton sets are open, so we should assume that each $x_n$ has an empty interior here?

Comment: @Korn: Right, that was a typo, sorry. Can you follow my answer now?

Comment: Since $\{x_n\}$ is closed and has an empty interior, we know each $\{x_n\}$ is nowhere dense, which is a contradiction to that $X$ cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets by Baire's category theorem. Is this right?

Comment: @Korn: Yes, exactly

Comment: where is completeness used in this argument?

Comment: @Math_Day: It is used to apply Baire's category theorem